# DbMigrator - verbose code-first migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When using Package Manager Console, you can run the following command:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
```

The `-Verbose` switch will write all attempted SQL commands to the console window, which is quite useful for debugging.

You can use the `DbMigrator` class to do the same in code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
//... (set up the config object)
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
migrator.Update();
```

Is there something like the `-Verbose` switch if you use the `DbMigrator` class? I looked all over the documentation, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See if this article solves your problem:

http://whiteknight.github.io/2013/01/26/efcodeonlymigrations.html

In short:

```
MigratorScriptingDecorator scripter = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
string script = scripter.ScriptUpdate(null, null);
```

Comment: This is indeed what I need. I actually used `MigratorLoggingDecorator` from the article. Thanks!